# jQuery - How to sequentially loop through an array to display only images with a certain property value one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting my code to work. I'm not entirely sure my function `displayHeartCards()` is right, and I'm getting an error in the console that there is an extra parentheses at the end when I wrap up my `(document).ready` function.

I am trying to display a deck of cards on a webpage. There will be one button on the page per suit of cards, so four buttons for Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades, respectively. When the button to display all the hearts cards is clicked, I want to display each heart card, starting with ace, one at a time in sequential order for 3 seconds each in the div id "displayArea". The cards cannot be shown more than once. Once all 52 cards have been displayed, I want the screen left blank. My images are stored, relative to my index.html file in "images/cards/Hearts/Ace.jpg".

Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i;

    //card object
    function card(name,suit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
    }; 

    var deck = [
        new card('Ace', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Two', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Three', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Four', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Five', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Six', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Seven', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Eight', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Nine', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Ten', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Jack', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Queen', 'Hearts'),
        new card('King', 'Hearts'),
        new card('Ace', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Two', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Three', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Four', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Five', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Six', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Seven', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Eight', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Nine', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Ten', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Jack', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Queen', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('King', 'Diamonds'),
        new card('Ace', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Two', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Three', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Four', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Five', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Six', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Seven', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Eight', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Nine', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Ten', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Jack', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Queen', 'Clubs'),
        new card('King', 'Clubs'),
        new card('Ace', 'Spades'),
        new card('Two', 'Spades'),
        new card('Three', 'Spades'),
        new card('Four', 'Spades'),
        new card('Five', 'Spades'),
        new card('Six', 'Spades'),
        new card('Seven', 'Spades'),
        new card('Eight', 'Spades'),
        new card('Nine', 'Spades'),
        new card('Ten', 'Spades'),
        new card('Jack', 'Spades'),
        new card('Queen', 'Spades'),
        new card('King', 'Spades')
    ];

    function displayHeartCards(){
        for (i = 0; i<12; i++){
            var c = deck[i];
            if(c.suit == "Hearts"){
                $("<img>").attr('src','images/cards/' + c.suit + '/' + c.name + '.jpg')
                    .appendTo("#displayArea")
                    .fadeIn('slow')
                    .delay(300)
                    .fadeOut('slow');
                displayedCards.push(c);
        };
    };

    $("#btnHearts").click(function(){
        displayHeartCards();
    });
    $("#btnDiamonds").click(function(){
        display();
    });
    $("#btnClubs").click(function(){
        display();
    });
    $("#btnSpades").click(function(){
        display();
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>Press a button to display each card in the suit</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button id="btnHearts">Show Hearts Cards</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="btnDiamonds">Show Diamonds Cards</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="btnClubs">Show Clubs Cards</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="btnSpades">Show Spades Cards</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="displayArea">
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to repost this because to be honest I was unclear of exactly what I needed the first time and my code was quite sloppy. Thank you.

Comment: "I am having trouble getting my code to work" doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure my function `displayHeartCards()` is right, and I'm getting an error in the console that there is an extra parentheses at the end when I wrap up my `(document).ready` function.

I added this to the post, thank you for the feedback. Cool username by the way.

Comment: You claim you needed to repost this question -- what was is wrong with [this perfectly acceptable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43037193/7256039) that was given on your previous thread?

Comment: What happened to the old question you posted?

Comment: @gyre That was a good answer for my muddled question, but in my code I had the cards being displayed randomly, rather than sequentially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Loop through and display images in an array with certain property value for specified time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036920/jquery-loop-through-and-display-images-in-an-array-with-certain-property-value)

Comment: You want to filter the array. Arrays have a method called filter. It takes a function that, given an element and its index, must return truthy if the element should be included in the result, otherwise it must return falsy. The correct solution is dead simple. `const values = [1, 2, 3,];` `const valuesToDisplay = values.filter(function(value) { .... });` After you build the display array, just render each item.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, kind of. But the question has been modified. When I first posted it I was not asking the proper questions and my code was sloppy.

Comment: @thenomadicmann disregard, you have properly concluded the question, sir. I will remove the votes shortly.

Comment: Forget my answer, the already linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036920/jquery-loop-through-and-display-images-in-an-array-with-certain-property-value does it nicely

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, but that answer displays them randomly. What would you tweak to display them sequentially?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Got it figured out!