# Jquery: Looping through images only shows last image

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through 1 suit of a deck of cards at a time with a 3-second pause in between them.

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <header>
        <h1>Click a suit and see all of the cards in it.</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <input type="button" id="Hearts" name="Hearts" value="Hearts" />
        <input type="button" id="Diamonds" name="Diamonds" value="Diamonds" />
        <input type="button" id="Clubs" name="Clubs" value="Clubs" />
        <input type="button" id="Spades" name="Spades" value="Spades" />
    </nav>
    <main>
        <p id="CardHere">
            <img src="" />
        </p>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p id="nameofcard"></p>
    </footer>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</div>
```

```
function ShowCards(DeckStartOfSuit) {

    for (i = DeckStartOfSuit; i < (DeckStartOfSuit + 13) ; i++) {
        var c = deck[i];
        setTimeout(function () { //for the 3 second delay

            $("main img").attr('src', 'images/' + c.suit + '/' + c.name + '.jpg')
                            .attr('alt', c.name + ' of ' + c.suit)
            $("footer p").text(c.name + ' of ' + c.suit)

        }, 3000); // is only happening at the end
    }
}

$("#Hearts").click(function () {
    ShowCards(0);
});

$("#Diamonds").click(function () {
    ShowCards(13);
});

$("#Clubs").click(function () {
    ShowCards(26);
});

$("#Spades").click(function () {
    ShowCards(39);
});
```

I made an array of a deck of cards and the buttons are passing in the index of the array that the suit starts at.

```
function card(name,suit,value) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
} 
var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts',11), 
    new card('Two', 'Hearts',2),
...
    new card('King', 'Spades',10)
```

The problem I am having is that only the last image is appearing. Each button will only make the king of that suit appear after 4 seconds.

Comment: add your HTML please

Comment: Yes, please replicate in a jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: wrap set time out function and then call your 3000 after your series of click functions if that's where your needing it.

Comment: I was able to find the answer I was looking for in a different post.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036920/jquery-loop-through-and-display-images-in-an-array-with-certain-property-value)